# SQL query that I have set up the algorithm but cannot write the code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I could not find keywords to describe in the title.

I have a problem and I just can explain with example, I have a table like this

```
user_id | transaction_id | bonus_id | created_at
 1.         1                  4       2021-05-01
 1          3                  65      2021-05-01
 1          4                  4       2021-05-02
 1          1                  5       2021-05-02
 1.         3                  76.     2021-05-03
 1          2                  5       2021-05-03
```

Due to a mistake I made in php here, transaction id 3 and bonus id 65 but the bonus id 4 that should be

I need to replace all transactions from transaction type 1 to the next transaction type 1 with the bonus id of the first transaction_type_1.

but of course I have to do this for every user. How can I do that?

Comment: 1. There is no column `transaction id`. What is that supposed to be?
2. `but the bonus id 4 should be`, do you mean `bonus_id 65 should be bonus_id 4` (just so we understand the problem)
3. `I need to replace all transactions from transaction_type 1 to the next transaction_type 1 with the bonus_id of the first_transaction_type_1`, do you mean add +1 to the transaction type?

Comment: Additionally, is there a difference between `1.` and `1` for `user_id`?

Comment: Sorry I fixed. I mean, the bonus_id of all data up to the other transaction_id 1 after the first transaction_id 1 must be the bonus_id value in transaction_id 1 before it. It's a little difficult to explain.

But I think you understand.

where the value of bonus_id 65 should actually be 4 and the value of bonus_id 76 should actually be 5

Comment: Yes, users can change, but this must be valid for each user's data, user 1's data must be updated up to its own transaction_id 1 values.